# Group / MapReduce in moongoose 3.6.15

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have model `Record` which looks like this:

```
{
    _id: '52278952a4bb5a7415000002',
    owner_id: '52278952a4bb5a7415000001',
    state: 'some_string'
}
```

I want to `GROUP` records collection by `owner_id` where `Record.state = 'some_string'` and count them for each owner. In other words I want to count all records with state = 'some_string' for each owner (specified in record as `owner_id`). How I can accomplish this? I searched in google for `mongoose group` and `mongoose map/reduce` but couldnt find anything that I would understand - and map reduce as I know puts results to new collection and I dont want to do this. I cant find any information in mongoose docs. Other examples contains some strange keywords in query like `$project` etc. Can anyone provide me good working example to this problem? It should be simple to do this I guess... I found out that there is method `Model.agregate(...)` method but cant find how to use it.

I use mongoose 3.6.15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this with `aggregate` and Mongoose:

```js
Record.aggregate([
    // Filter the docs to just those you want to include
    {$match: {state: 'some_string'}},
    // Group by owner_id and count them per owner
    {$group: {_id: '$owner_id', count: {$sum: 1}}}
], function (err, results) { ... });
```

Docs on `aggregate` can be found [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/).  It can be intimidating at first, but spend an hour or so reading over the docs and understanding the examples and you'll get the hang of it fairly quickly.